# What book has the Mage Pyromancer Spell School in it?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard, product-identification

I want to play a Mage Pyromancer but can't seem to remember the book with the Spell School in it.

What book is the Mage School in?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Please take the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you've got a minute.

Answer (score 4):

The pyromancy mage school is found in **Dragon** magazine, issue **391**. It is detailed in the *Class Acts: Essentials Pyromancer* article on page 41 of that issue.